# Get surface normal image of the scene

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, normals, blend-files, normal-map

I have a car scene with some cameras in it. I have written code to render the car image as seen by the camera. What I want to do is get a surface normal map similar to the photos below.

[image]
[image]

I tried searching for how to get this done, but I couldn't find anything. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old tread, but I just stumbled by.. 
A fast way to do this, is to use the Matcap preview in the 3D view, and select the "normal sphere" in the matcap images/balls.
Then simply screengrap!

If this is not good enough, it would be easy to make a material that would do it.